# Avoid creating temporary vars for params which are not defaulted?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

This might sound a crazy question possibly.

in my C++ code, I created a method like this

```
void Func(int & param_1, bool & param_2, float & param_3, double & param_4) {
   //some logic
}
```

So I call the method in `main` like below:

```
int i_val;
bool b_val;
float f_val;
double d_val;

//invoke Func here
Func(i_val, b_val, f_val, d_val);
```

**Question:** Is there some way to avoid creation of the temporary variables  `i_val, b_val, f_val` and so on ? And create them in the line of the invocation itself ?

I am interested only in creating `i_val` and `b_val` and get their values.  `f_val` and `d_val` are unnecessary for me but necessary in some other call which doesn't concern me here. Is there a way to avoid creating the temporary vars just to pass each param into the call ?

**I know we can make the last 2 params as default params** but having default params makes the function params oblivious to the caller. Is there a way without making the last 2 params default ? sort of create the float and double variables on the fly at the moment of invoking the method

*I understand that I will get cross-questions on why you do not want to use default params but just checking if there is a possibility :)*

Comment: use function overloading

Comment: Unless there's a very good reason not to do that, I'd return a struct. Then you get what you want from it. By doing this you can declare the result variable const, by the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have *four* out parameters, like you do here:

```
void Func(int & param_1, bool & param_2, float & param_3, double & param_4);
```

That suggests that really you want to return one objects with 4 members, like:

```
std::tuple<int, bool, float, double> Func();
```

or:

```
struct X {
    int some;
    bool meaningful;
    float names;
    double here;
};

X Func();
```

That way, you can just write:

```
auto res = Func();
```

and then just use the fields you want.

---

In C++17, with structured bindings, that can be:

```
auto [ival, bval, _1, _2] = Func();
```

There's not really a clear way to express the notion that you don't care about the 3rd and 4th members, but this isn't bad.

Comment: That's *the* sensible advice here. I'd also encourage the use of const on the result variable unless there's a compelling reason not to.

Comment: @gd1 The compelling reason not to is so you can move from the result.

Comment: If you don't have to (and, well, if the struct is made of those things...) you'd rather have one less variable you can screw up, the compiler helpfully preventing you from doing so.

Comment: I cannot get "`operator tie`" technique to work.  Sad.

Answer (score 4):

C++ rules of thumb:
references when you make something mandatory
pointers when you make something optional. Of course, the code in that function needs to account for nullptr that can be passed.

Make it

```
void Func(int* pParam_1, bool* pParam_2, float* pParam_3, double* pParam_4) {
// some logic
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvote either. Let's wipe it out. This is an old-fashioned way, but that doesn't make it a bad way.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think a function taking four pointers as *potentially optional* output (nonconst) parameters, in C++, is a horror show.

Comment: @gd1: there are other ways. But this one is simple and *depending on context and requirement* can be perfectly appropriate. That being said, if you are speaking of a general design, a function take for optional io parameters is weird whatever the language...

Comment: @gd1 I totally agree and wouldn't do that myself, but with that little context from the original question it's a valid choice.

Comment: The OP can probably design the function however they want, so it'd make sense to suggest a design that works in most cases and doesn't look so alarmingly old-fashioned and error-prone. Unless there's a compelling case to follow that route (and I am very sceptical there is in this case even though I can't look at the whole program)...

Comment: trying to figure if I can use the new `std::optional` offering from C++

Answer (score 2):

With a non-`const` reference such as you have, no. You could consider function overloading, returning a `struct`containing those values, or even a `std::tuple` from C++11 onwards. (Note that `std::tuple` gets a significant upgrade in C++14.)

It would make things nicer if you made your references `const`<sup>*</sup> and rely on the returned values for the results. Then you can pass *anonymous temporaries* to your function at the call site:

```
/*something*/ Func(const int& param_1, const bool& param_2, /*etc*/) {
}
```

and call with `Func(1, true)` etc. With `const` references, you can even supply default values:

```
/*something*/ Func(const int& param_1 = 1, const bool& params_2 = true, /*etc*/){
```

---

<sup>*</sup> Some compilers allow *binding* of an anonymous temporary to a non-`const` reference as an extension / unintentional bug. But I wouldn't rely on that if I were you.

Comment: Unless there is a very strong case (and I seriously doubt it) against it, I'd return a struct.

Comment: @gd1: I agree, personally I don't like tuples, std::pair is borderline for me.

Comment: @Bathsheba How is `pair` better than `tuple`?  I'd order them the other way around; `tuple` at least is useful in generic code to bundle data for later consumption; meanwhile `pair` is code smell everywhere.

Comment: Even though they are useful tools in many situations, especially `std::tuple` with templates, I don't think any client-facing interface should neither accept nor return a `std::pair` or a `std::tuple`. They have no semantics, they're just "a few things". When `std::tuple` was introduced, I was quivering as I thought "anyone too lazy to be bothered to write a struct will return a `std::tuple` of unnamed 'things'". I didn't have to wait for long.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but you have to be aware that the dummy temporaries will die at the end of the full-expression:

```
template <typename T>
T& stay(T&& x = T()) {
    return x;
}

void Func(int& param_1, bool& param_2, float& param_3, double& param_4) {
   //some logic
}

int main() {
    int arg_1; float arg_3;
    Func(arg_1, stay<bool>(), arg_3, stay(42.0));
}
```

`stay` converts rvalue to lvalue, and so is opposite of `std::move`.

Comment: I don't understand why you `std::remove_reference_t`; and its existence confused me and I answered basically a duplicate of yours.  In what situation is that `remove_reference_t` needed?

Comment: @Yakk you are correct, it is superfluous here; appended lvalue reference will collapse whatever ref-qualifiers `T` has. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

> sort of create the float and double variables on the fly at the moment of invoking the method

To do this, create an anonymous temporary with the value you want.  Then cast it so you can bind to an lvalue reference.

```
template<class T>
T& as_lvalue(T&& t={}){return t;}

void Func(int& param_1, bool& param_2, float& param_3, double& param_4) {
}

int main() {
  int a1;
  float a3;
  Func(a1, as_lvalue(false), a3, as_lvalue(3.14));
}
```

`as_lvalue` takes an rvalue (or lvalue!) and casts it to an lvalue of the same type.  It can then bind to an lvalue reference, and be discarded at the end of the expression.

If you don't care what their value is you can even do:

```
int main() {
  int a1;
  float a3;
  Func(a1, as_lvalue<bool>(), a3, as_lvalue<double>());
}
```

Note that using reference parameters as pure-out parameters is a bit of code smell.  When you use them, reference parameters should be in-out parameters; their value coming in and out should have use.

Parameters where you both carry data in and take it out are also dangerous, as it makes it harder to reason about the behavior of the function.

One approach that is extremely clean is to take and return a struct.

```
struct FuncArgs {
  int param_1;
  bool param_2;
  float param_3;
  double param_4;
};
FuncArgs Func(FuncArgs) {
  //some logic
}
```

people can call it like this:

```
Func({3, true, 42.f, 3.14})
```

and get the return data like this:

```
auto r = Func({3, true, 42.f, 3.14})
int param1 = r.param1;
bool param2 = r.param2;
```

ignoring the returned `param3` and `param4`.

In C++17, they can even do:

```
auto[param1, param2, donotcare, alsodonotcare] = Func({3, true, 42.f, 3.14});
```

sadly there is no way to completely skip the `donotcare` and `alsodonotcare` fields.

If, however, your data is pure-out results, we just strip the `FuncArgs` arguments.

Now, modifying every location that calls `Func` may be annoying; but thanks to the wonder of overloading, we can just write:

```
inline FuncArgs Func() {
  FuncArgs args;
  Func(args.param1, args.param2, args.param3, args.param4);
  return args;
}
```

or

```
inline FuncArgs Func(FuncArgs args) {
  Func(args.param1, args.param2, args.param3, args.param4);
  return args;
}
```

and both happily live beside each other.  Existing code need not be touched; new code is.

Comment: Doesn't lifetime of the default temporary bound to `t` end at the end of `at_lvalue`?

Comment: @yurikilochek No, it ends at the "end of the line" where you call `as_lvalue`.  Binding to a reference doesn't shorten their lifetime.  The `{}` exists at the location of call, and the explicit `false` also there.  Annoyingly, I cannot work out how to do an `ignored_reference()` construct without using a `static` variable; `operator T()` cannot take an argument!